# Different .svg codes? How to convert one to another?

Tags: svg

I am currently working with some .svg's and I was wondering why there are so many different ways to make a svg and how I can change one variation to the other style.

For example this one:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/BlankMap-FlatWorld6.svg

Creates outlines of countries like this: [Source](http://view-source:https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/BlankMap-FlatWorld6.svg)

But others like this one:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/BlankMap-Equirectangular.svg

Creates outlines of countries like this: [Source](http://view-source:https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/BlankMap-Equirectangular.svg)

These previous two look a bit like eachother, but then we also have this one:
https://simplemaps.com/resources/svg-world (source on this page as well)

And this one creates it outlines like this:

```
 d="m 1369.9,333.8 -5.4,0 -3.8,-0.5 -2.5,2.9 -2.1,0.7 -1.5,1.3 -2.6,-2.1 -1,-5.4 -1.6,-0.3 0,-2 -3.2,-1.5 -1.7,2.3 0.2,2.6 -0.6,0.9 -3.2,-0.1 -0.9,3 -2.1,-1.3 -3.3,2.1 -1.8,-0.8 -4.3,-1.4 -2.9,0 -1.6,-0.2 -2.9,-1.7 -0.3,2.3 -4.1,1.2 0.1,5.2 -2.5,2 -4,0.9 -0.4,3 -3.9,0.8 -5.9,-2.4 -0.5,8 -0.5,4.7 2.5,0.9 -1.6,3.5 2.7,5.1 1.1,4 4.3,1.1 1.1,4 -3.9,5.8 9.6,3.2 5.3,-0.9 3.3,0.8 0.9,-1.4 3.8,0.5 6.6,-2.6 -0.8,-5.4 2.3,-3.6 4,0 0.2,-1.7 4,-0.9 2.1,0.6 1.7,-1.8 -1.1,-3.8 1.5,-3.8 3,-1.6 -3,-4.2 5.1,0.2 0.9,-2.3 -0.8,-2.5 2,-2.7 -1.4,-3.2 -1.9,-2.8 2.4,-2.8 5.3,-1.3 5.8,-0.8 2.4,-1.2 2.8,-0.7 -1.4,-1.9 z"
```

I understand that the first two are just writing all the coordinates and the third one just gives the first coordinates and then keeps giving the distance from the previous coordinate to the next one. What I don't understand is how I can change the code from the second example so it looks like the third example.

I made an Excel that changes the code, so I went from this:

```
d="M74.891 37.232L74.84 37.225L74.767 37.249L74.739 37.286L74.727 37.291L74.669 37.267L74.559 37.237L74.372 37.158L74.376 37.137L74.498 37.057L74.526 37.031L74.541 37.022L74.431 36.984L74.195 36.897L74.039 36.826L74.002 36.823L73.908 36.853L73.769 36.888L73.732 36.888L73.411 36.882L73.117 36.869L72.994 36.852L72.766 36.835L72.623 36.83L72.531 36.802L72.431 36.766L72.327 36.742L72.25 36.735L72.157 36.701L72.096 36.634L71.921 36.534L71.822 36.486L71.773 36.432L71.716 36.427L71.62 36.436L71.546 36.378L71.463 36.293L71.313 36.171L71.233 36.122L71.185 36.042L71.22 36.001L71.343 35.939L71.398 35.88L71.428 35.834L71.484 35.715L71.519 35.598L71.572 35.547L71.587 35.461L71.601 35.408L71.572 35.37L71.545 35.329L71.545 35.289L71.577 35.248L71.605 35.212L71.62 35.183L71.602 35.151L71.545 35.101L71.517 35.051L71.455 34.967L71.358 34.91L71.294 34.868L71.226 34.78L71.113 34.682L71.066 34.6L71.016 34.555L70.966 34.53L70.979 34.486L71.023 34.431L71.096 34.369L71.092 34.273L71.089 34.204L71.091 34.12L71.052 34.05L70.848 33.982L70.654 33.952L70.416 33.95L70.326 33.961L70.254 33.976L69.995 34.052L69.89 34.007L69.868 33.898L70.057 33.72L70.134 33.621L70.22 33.455L70.284 33.369L70.261 33.289L70.09 33.198L69.92 33.112L69.704 33.095L69.568 33.064L69.502 33.02L69.453 32.833L69.405 32.764L69.405 32.683L69.359 32.59L69.29 32.531L69.241 32.434L69.257 32.249L69.279 31.937L69.187 31.838L69.083 31.738L68.973 31.667L68.869 31.634L68.782 31.646L68.714 31.708L68.673 31.76L68.598 31.803L68.521 31.794L68.443 31.754L68.32 31.768L68.214 31.807L68.161 31.803L68.13 31.763L68.017 31.678L67.74 31.548L67.627 31.539L67.578 31.506L67.598 31.453L67.647 31.41L67.733 31.379L67.738 31.344L67.661 31.313L67.596 31.278L67.453 31.235L67.287 31.218L67.116 31.243L67.028 31.3L66.924 31.306L66.829 31.264L66.731 31.195L66.624 31.046L66.596 31.02L66.567 30.997L66.497 30.965L66.397 30.912L66.347 30.803L66.287 30.608L66.301 30.503L66.305 30.321L66.282 30.193L66.238 30.11L66.247 30.043L66.313 29.969L66.287 29.92L66.231 29.866L66.177 29.836L65.962 29.779L65.666 29.701L65.471 29.652L65.18 29.578L65.095 29.559L64.919 29.553L64.827 29.564L64.704 29.567L64.521 29.565L64.394 29.544L64.266 29.507L64.172 29.46L64.118 29.414L64.099 29.392L63.971 29.43L63.568 29.498L62.477 29.408L62.373 29.425L62.001 29.53L61.521 29.666L61.224 29.749L60.843 29.859L61.104 30.128L61.332 30.364L61.559 30.599L61.784 30.832L61.811 30.913L61.814 31.073L61.755 31.285L61.66 31.382L61.346 31.422L61.111 31.451L60.854 31.483L60.821 31.495L60.792 31.661L60.804 31.734L60.788 31.877L60.79 31.987L60.827 32.168L60.829 32.249L60.71 32.6L60.644 32.794L60.577 32.995L60.562 33.059L60.561 33.138L60.718 33.324L60.767 33.364L60.859 33.456L60.917 33.505L60.907 33.539L60.806 33.559L60.655 33.56L60.574 33.588L60.511 33.639L60.486 33.712L60.527 33.842L60.486 34.095L60.57 34.22L60.643 34.307L60.889 34.319L60.804 34.418L60.763 34.475L60.736 34.492L60.726 34.518L60.739 34.545L60.802 34.555L60.845 34.588L60.915 34.634L60.951 34.654L60.958 34.71L60.991 34.75L61.04 34.799L61.08 34.856L61.07 34.922L61.107 35.001L61.123 35.051L61.15 35.094L61.126 35.157L61.107 35.209L61.1 35.272L61.14 35.289L61.189 35.312L61.199 35.362L61.226 35.424L61.245 35.474L61.279 35.514L61.282 35.553L61.262 35.62L61.345 35.63L61.378 35.593L61.422 35.546L61.543 35.458L61.621 35.432L61.72 35.419L61.841 35.431L61.938 35.448L61.984 35.444L62.09 35.38L62.213 35.29L62.253 35.25L62.271 35.189L62.308 35.171L62.387 35.231L62.463 35.251L62.533 35.24L62.611 35.233L62.688 35.255L62.723 35.271L62.858 35.35L62.98 35.409L63.057 35.446L63.084 35.568L63.119 35.638L63.17 35.678L63.151 35.728L63.13 35.767L63.109 35.819L63.13 35.846L63.179 35.858L63.302 35.858L63.517 35.913L63.697 35.968L63.862 36.012L63.938 36.02L64.01 36.012L64.042 36.025L64.051 36.068L64.092 36.113L64.184 36.149L64.358 36.226L64.511 36.341L64.566 36.428L64.603 36.555L64.674 36.75L64.753 36.965L64.782 37.059L64.816 37.132L64.952 37.194L65.09 37.238L65.304 37.247L65.555 37.251L65.608 37.368L65.641 37.468L65.683 37.519L65.744 37.561L65.765 37.569L65.901 37.508L66.108 37.415L66.35 37.368L66.472 37.345L66.522 37.348L66.828 37.371L67.069 37.335L67.195 37.235L67.32 37.21L67.442 37.258L67.517 37.267L67.547 37.236L67.607 37.223L67.7 37.227L67.753 37.2L67.759 37.172L67.766 37.14L67.834 37.064L67.958 36.972L68.068 36.95L68.212 37.022L68.261 37.013L68.285 37.036L68.3 37.088L68.387 37.137L68.547 37.183L68.637 37.224L68.669 37.258L68.723 37.268L68.782 37.258L68.824 37.271L68.838 37.303L68.855 37.317L68.885 37.328L68.912 37.334L68.96 37.325L69.05 37.267L69.18 37.158L69.265 37.108L69.304 37.117L69.354 37.15L69.415 37.208L69.43 37.291L69.399 37.399L69.42 37.487L69.492 37.553L69.626 37.594L69.821 37.61L69.941 37.6L69.985 37.566L70.045 37.547L70.12 37.543L70.189 37.582L70.251 37.664L70.255 37.765L70.199 37.886L70.215 37.924L70.239 37.941L70.313 37.985L70.418 38.075L70.519 38.192L70.616 38.334L70.736 38.423L70.879 38.456L71.052 38.418L71.256 38.307L71.333 38.17L71.283 38.008L71.279 37.918L71.32 37.902L71.39 37.906L71.488 37.932L71.552 37.933L71.582 37.91L71.58 37.864L71.546 37.796L71.505 37.603L71.48 37.436L71.455 37.272L71.433 37.128L71.472 37.015L71.531 36.845L71.598 36.733L71.666 36.697L71.734 36.684L71.802 36.694L71.942 36.766L72.154 36.901L72.359 36.983L72.657 37.029L72.757 37.173L72.896 37.268L73.211 37.409L73.383 37.462L73.481 37.472L73.605 37.446L73.633 37.437L73.657 37.43L73.721 37.419L73.734 37.376L73.717 37.329L73.649 37.291L73.628 37.262L73.653 37.239L73.75 37.232L73.949 37.283L74.078 37.316L74.167 37.329L74.203 37.372L74.26 37.415L74.349 37.419L74.445 37.396L74.524 37.382L74.659 37.394L74.731 37.357L74.831 37.286L74.875 37.242L74.891 37.232Z"
```

To this:

```
d="m 37.232,74.891 0,-51 -7,-73 24,-28 37,-12 5,-58 -24,-110 -30,-187 -79,4 -21,122 -80,28 -26,15 -9,-110 -38,-236 -87,-156 -71,-37 -3,-94 30,-139 35,-37 0,-321 -6,-294 -13,-123 -17,-228 -17,-143 -5,-92 -28,-100 -36,-104 -24,-77 -7,-93 -34,-61 -67,-175 -100,-99 -48,-49 -54,-57 -5,-96 9,-74 -58,-83 -85,-150 -122,-80 -49,-48 -80,35 -41,123 -62,55 -59,30 -46,56 -119,35 -117,53 -51,15 -86,14 -53,-29 -38,-27 -41,0 -40,32 -41,28 -36,15 -29,-18 -32,-57 -50,-28 -50,-62 -84,-97 -57,-64 -42,-68 -88,-113 -98,-47 -82,-50 -45,-50 -25,13 -44,44 -55,73 -62,-4 -96,-3 -69,2 -84,-39 -70,-204 -68,-194 -30,-238 -2,-90 11,-72 15,-259 76,-105 -45,-22 -109,189 -178,77 -99,86 -166,64 -86,-23 -80,-171 -91,-170 -86,-216 -17,-136 -31,-66 -44,-49 -187,-48 -69,0 -81,-46 -93,-69 -59,-49 -97,16 -185,22 -312,-92 -99,-104 -100,-110 -71,-104 -33,-87 12,-68 62,-41 52,-75 43,-77 -9,-78 -40,-123 14,-106 39,-53 -4,-31 -40,-113 -85,-277 -130,-113 -9,-49 -33,20 -53,49 -43,86 -31,5 -35,-77 -31,-65 -35,-143 -43,-166 -17,-171 25,-88 57,-104 6,-95 -42,-98 -69,-107 -149,-28 -26,-29 -23,-70 -32,-100 -53,-50 -109,-60 -195,14 -105,4 -182,-23 -128,-44 -83,9 -67,66 -74,-26 -49,-56 -54,-54 -30,-215 -57,-296 -78,-195 -49,-291 -74,-85 -19,-176 -6,-92 11,-123 3,-183 -2,-127 -21,-128 -37,-94 -47,-54 -46,-19 -22,-128 38,-403 68,-1091 -90,-104 17,-372 105,-480 136,-297 83,-381 110,261 269,228 236,227 235,225 233,27 81,3 160,-59 212,-95 97,-314 40,-235 29,-257 32,-33 12,-29 166,12 73,-16 143,2 110,37 181,2 81,-119 351,-66 194,-67 201,-15 64,-1 79,157 186,49 40,92 92,58 49,-10 34,-101 20,-151 1,-81 28,-63 51,-25 73,41 130,-41 253,84 125,73 87,246 12,-85 99,-41 57,-27 17,-10 26,13 27,63 10,43 33,70 46,36 20,7 56,33 40,49 49,40 57,-10 66,37 79,16 50,27 43,-24 63,-19 52,-7 63,40 17,49 23,10 50,27 62,19 50,34 40,3 39,-20 67,83 10,33 -37,44 -47,121 -88,78 -26,99 -13,121 12,97 17,46 -4,106 -64,123 -90,40 -40,18 -61,37 -18,79 60,76 20,70 -11,78 -7,77 22,35 16,135 79,122 59,77 37,27 122,35 70,51 40,-19 50,-21 39,-21 52,21 27,49 12,123 0,215 55,180 55,165 44,76 8,72 -8,32 13,9 43,41 45,92 36,174 77,153 115,55 87,37 127,71 195,79 215,29 94,34 73,136 62,138 44,214 9,251 4,53 117,33 100,42 51,61 42,21 8,136 -61,207 -93,242 -47,122 -23,50 3,306 23,241 -36,126 -100,125 -25,122 48,75 9,30 -31,60 -13,93 4,53 -27,6 -28,7 -32,68 -76,124 -92,110 -22,144 72,49 -9,24 23,15 52,87 49,160 46,90 41,32 34,54 10,59 -10,42 13,14 32,17 14,30 11,27 6,48 -9,90 -58,130 -109,85 -50,39 9,50 33,61 58,15 83,-31 108,21 88,72 66,134 41,195 16,120 -10,44 -34,60 -19,75 -4,69 39,62 82,4 101,-56 121,16 38,24 17,74 44,105 90,101 117,97 142,120 89,143 33,173 -38,204 -111,77 -137,-50 -162,-4 -90,41 -16,70 4,98 26,64 1,30 -23,-2 -46,-34 -68,-41 -193,-25 -167,-25 -164,-22 -144,39 -113,59 -170,67 -112,68 -36,68 -13,68 10,140 72,212 135,205 82,298 46,100 144,139 95,315 141,172 53,98 10,124 -26,28 -9,24 -7,64 -11,13 -43,-17 -47,-68 -38,-21 -29,25 -23,97 -7,199 51,129 33,89 13,36 43,57 43,89 4,96 -23,79 -14,135 12,72 -37,100 -71,44 -44,16 z"
```

This should outline afghanistan and it does, but it somehow isn't oriented the right way?

Is this because of the other code before it? (I think it does) This is the complete .svg code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   version="1.1"
   width="360"
   height="180"
   viewBox="0 0 360 180"
   id="svg928"
   sodipodi:docname="BlankMap-Equirectangular2.svg"
   inkscape:version="0.92.2 (5c3e80d, 2017-08-06)">

  <defs
     id="defs932" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     objecttolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     guidetolerance="10"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:window-width="1680"
     inkscape:window-height="988"
     id="namedview930"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="3.0484159"
     inkscape:cx="593.00732"
     inkscape:cy="460.46398"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="positioner" />
  <style
     type="text/css"
     id="style2">
.country {
  opacity:1;
  fill:#444444;
  fill-opacity:1;
  fill-rule:evenodd;
  stroke:none;
}
/*
Example for painting countries: 
.GBR {
  fill: #0000aa !important;
}
*/
</style>
  <path
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     id="NL"
     data-name="Afghanistan"
     data-id="NL"
     d="m 37.232,74.891 0,-51 -7,-73 24,-28 37,-12 5,-58 -24,-110 -30,-187 -79,4 -21,122 -80,28 -26,15 -9,-110 -38,-236 -87,-156 -71,-37 -3,-94 30,-139 35,-37 0,-321 -6,-294 -13,-123 -17,-228 -17,-143 -5,-92 -28,-100 -36,-104 -24,-77 -7,-93 -34,-61 -67,-175 -100,-99 -48,-49 -54,-57 -5,-96 9,-74 -58,-83 -85,-150 -122,-80 -49,-48 -80,35 -41,123 -62,55 -59,30 -46,56 -119,35 -117,53 -51,15 -86,14 -53,-29 -38,-27 -41,0 -40,32 -41,28 -36,15 -29,-18 -32,-57 -50,-28 -50,-62 -84,-97 -57,-64 -42,-68 -88,-113 -98,-47 -82,-50 -45,-50 -25,13 -44,44 -55,73 -62,-4 -96,-3 -69,2 -84,-39 -70,-204 -68,-194 -30,-238 -2,-90 11,-72 15,-259 76,-105 -45,-22 -109,189 -178,77 -99,86 -166,64 -86,-23 -80,-171 -91,-170 -86,-216 -17,-136 -31,-66 -44,-49 -187,-48 -69,0 -81,-46 -93,-69 -59,-49 -97,16 -185,22 -312,-92 -99,-104 -100,-110 -71,-104 -33,-87 12,-68 62,-41 52,-75 43,-77 -9,-78 -40,-123 14,-106 39,-53 -4,-31 -40,-113 -85,-277 -130,-113 -9,-49 -33,20 -53,49 -43,86 -31,5 -35,-77 -31,-65 -35,-143 -43,-166 -17,-171 25,-88 57,-104 6,-95 -42,-98 -69,-107 -149,-28 -26,-29 -23,-70 -32,-100 -53,-50 -109,-60 -195,14 -105,4 -182,-23 -128,-44 -83,9 -67,66 -74,-26 -49,-56 -54,-54 -30,-215 -57,-296 -78,-195 -49,-291 -74,-85 -19,-176 -6,-92 11,-123 3,-183 -2,-127 -21,-128 -37,-94 -47,-54 -46,-19 -22,-128 38,-403 68,-1091 -90,-104 17,-372 105,-480 136,-297 83,-381 110,261 269,228 236,227 235,225 233,27 81,3 160,-59 212,-95 97,-314 40,-235 29,-257 32,-33 12,-29 166,12 73,-16 143,2 110,37 181,2 81,-119 351,-66 194,-67 201,-15 64,-1 79,157 186,49 40,92 92,58 49,-10 34,-101 20,-151 1,-81 28,-63 51,-25 73,41 130,-41 253,84 125,73 87,246 12,-85 99,-41 57,-27 17,-10 26,13 27,63 10,43 33,70 46,36 20,7 56,33 40,49 49,40 57,-10 66,37 79,16 50,27 43,-24 63,-19 52,-7 63,40 17,49 23,10 50,27 62,19 50,34 40,3 39,-20 67,83 10,33 -37,44 -47,121 -88,78 -26,99 -13,121 12,97 17,46 -4,106 -64,123 -90,40 -40,18 -61,37 -18,79 60,76 20,70 -11,78 -7,77 22,35 16,135 79,122 59,77 37,27 122,35 70,51 40,-19 50,-21 39,-21 52,21 27,49 12,123 0,215 55,180 55,165 44,76 8,72 -8,32 13,9 43,41 45,92 36,174 77,153 115,55 87,37 127,71 195,79 215,29 94,34 73,136 62,138 44,214 9,251 4,53 117,33 100,42 51,61 42,21 8,136 -61,207 -93,242 -47,122 -23,50 3,306 23,241 -36,126 -100,125 -25,122 48,75 9,30 -31,60 -13,93 4,53 -27,6 -28,7 -32,68 -76,124 -92,110 -22,144 72,49 -9,24 23,15 52,87 49,160 46,90 41,32 34,54 10,59 -10,42 13,14 32,17 14,30 11,27 6,48 -9,90 -58,130 -109,85 -50,39 9,50 33,61 58,15 83,-31 108,21 88,72 66,134 41,195 16,120 -10,44 -34,60 -19,75 -4,69 39,62 82,4 101,-56 121,16 38,24 17,74 44,105 90,101 117,97 142,120 89,143 33,173 -38,204 -111,77 -137,-50 -162,-4 -90,41 -16,70 4,98 26,64 1,30 -23,-2 -46,-34 -68,-41 -193,-25 -167,-25 -164,-22 -144,39 -113,59 -170,67 -112,68 -36,68 -13,68 10,140 72,212 135,205 82,298 46,100 144,139 95,315 141,172 53,98 10,124 -26,28 -9,24 -7,64 -11,13 -43,-17 -47,-68 -38,-21 -29,25 -23,97 -7,199 51,129 33,89 13,36 43,57 43,89 4,96 -23,79 -14,135 12,72 -37,100 -71,44 -44,16 z"
     style="fill:#f2f2f2;fill-rule:evenodd" />
</svg>
```

I tried changing everything to the code of the other .svg's but nothing has worked so far. I know it has to do something with this code before it, but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: So basically my question is: why is my drawing of afghanistan turned the wrong way? Even when I copied it from something that was the right way.

EDIT 2:
User ccprog was correct, my Excel formula didn't work as intended and it made X replace Y and Y replace X. Here is my new code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   version="1.1"
   width="360"
   height="180"
   viewBox="0 0 360 180"
   id="svg928"
   sodipodi:docname="BlankMap-Equirectangular2.svg"
   inkscape:version="0.92.2 (5c3e80d, 2017-08-06)">
  <metadata
     id="metadata934">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs
     id="defs932" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     objecttolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     guidetolerance="10"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:window-width="1680"
     inkscape:window-height="988"
     id="namedview930"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="3.0484159"
     inkscape:cx="198.15912"
     inkscape:cy="129.24454"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="positioner" />
  <style
     type="text/css"
     id="style2">
.country {
  opacity:1;
  fill:#444444;
  fill-opacity:1;
  fill-rule:evenodd;
  stroke:none;
}
/*
Example for painting countries: 
.GBR {
  fill: #0000aa !important;
}
*/
</style>
  <g
     id="positioner"
     transform="translate(180, 90) scale(1, -1)">
  <path
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
     id="NL"
     data-name="Afghanistan"
     data-id="NL"
     d="m 74.891,37.232 -51,-7 -73,24 -28,37 -12,5 -58,-24 -110,-30 -187,-79 4,-21 122,-80 28,-26 15,-9 -110,-38 -236,-87 -156,-71 -37,-3 -94,30 -139,35 -37,0 -321,-6 -294,-13 -123,-17 -228,-17 -143,-5 -92,-28 -100,-36 -104,-24 -77,-7 -93,-34 -61,-67 -175,-100 -99,-48 -49,-54 -57,-5 -96,9 -74,-58 -83,-85 -150,-122 -80,-49 -48,-80 35,-41 123,-62 55,-59 30,-46 56,-119 35,-117 53,-51 15,-86 14,-53 -29,-38 -27,-41 0,-40 32,-41 28,-36 15,-29 -18,-32 -57,-50 -28,-50 -62,-84 -97,-57 -64,-42 -68,-88 -113,-98 -47,-82 -50,-45 -50,-25 13,-44 44,-55 73,-62 -4,-96 -3,-69 2,-84 -39,-70 -204,-68 -194,-30 -238,-2 -90,11 -72,15 -259,76 -105,-45 -22,-109 189,-178 77,-99 86,-166 64,-86 -23,-80 -171,-91 -170,-86 -216,-17 -136,-31 -66,-44 -49,-187 -48,-69 0,-81 -46,-93 -69,-59 -49,-97 16,-185 22,-312 -92,-99 -104,-100 -110,-71 -104,-33 -87,12 -68,62 -41,52 -75,43 -77,-9 -78,-40 -123,14 -106,39 -53,-4 -31,-40 -113,-85 -277,-130 -113,-9 -49,-33 20,-53 49,-43 86,-31 5,-35 -77,-31 -65,-35 -143,-43 -166,-17 -171,25 -88,57 -104,6 -95,-42 -98,-69 -107,-149 -28,-26 -29,-23 -70,-32 -100,-53 -50,-109 -60,-195 14,-105 4,-182 -23,-128 -44,-83 9,-67 66,-74 -26,-49 -56,-54 -54,-30 -215,-57 -296,-78 -195,-49 -291,-74 -85,-19 -176,-6 -92,11 -123,3 -183,-2 -127,-21 -128,-37 -94,-47 -54,-46 -19,-22 -128,38 -403,68 -1091,-90 -104,17 -372,105 -480,136 -297,83 -381,110 261,269 228,236 227,235 225,233 27,81 3,160 -59,212 -95,97 -314,40 -235,29 -257,32 -33,12 -29,166 12,73 -16,143 2,110 37,181 2,81 -119,351 -66,194 -67,201 -15,64 -1,79 157,186 49,40 92,92 58,49 -10,34 -101,20 -151,1 -81,28 -63,51 -25,73 41,130 -41,253 84,125 73,87 246,12 -85,99 -41,57 -27,17 -10,26 13,27 63,10 43,33 70,46 36,20 7,56 33,40 49,49 40,57 -10,66 37,79 16,50 27,43 -24,63 -19,52 -7,63 40,17 49,23 10,50 27,62 19,50 34,40 3,39 -20,67 83,10 33,-37 44,-47 121,-88 78,-26 99,-13 121,12 97,17 46,-4 106,-64 123,-90 40,-40 18,-61 37,-18 79,60 76,20 70,-11 78,-7 77,22 35,16 135,79 122,59 77,37 27,122 35,70 51,40 -19,50 -21,39 -21,52 21,27 49,12 123,0 215,55 180,55 165,44 76,8 72,-8 32,13 9,43 41,45 92,36 174,77 153,115 55,87 37,127 71,195 79,215 29,94 34,73 136,62 138,44 214,9 251,4 53,117 33,100 42,51 61,42 21,8 136,-61 207,-93 242,-47 122,-23 50,3 306,23 241,-36 126,-100 125,-25 122,48 75,9 30,-31 60,-13 93,4 53,-27 6,-28 7,-32 68,-76 124,-92 110,-22 144,72 49,-9 24,23 15,52 87,49 160,46 90,41 32,34 54,10 59,-10 42,13 14,32 17,14 30,11 27,6 48,-9 90,-58 130,-109 85,-50 39,9 50,33 61,58 15,83 -31,108 21,88 72,66 134,41 195,16 120,-10 44,-34 60,-19 75,-4 69,39 62,82 4,101 -56,121 16,38 24,17 74,44 105,90 101,117 97,142 120,89 143,33 173,-38 204,-111 77,-137 -50,-162 -4,-90 41,-16 70,4 98,26 64,1 30,-23 -2,-46 -34,-68 -41,-193 -25,-167 -25,-164 -22,-144 39,-113 59,-170 67,-112 68,-36 68,-13 68,10 140,72 212,135 205,82 298,46 100,144 139,95 315,141 172,53 98,10 124,-26 28,-9 24,-7 64,-11 13,-43 -17,-47 -68,-38 -21,-29 25,-23 97,-7 199,51 129,33 89,13 36,43 57,43 89,4 96,-23 79,-14 135,12 72,-37 100,-71 44,-44 16,-10"
     style="fill:#f2f2f2;fill-rule:evenodd" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

How do I fix the positioning of this? I tried playing around with the viewBox and the width and height, but it never really looked right/better.

Thanks again.

Comment: Your Excel function seems to have swapped x and y coordinates: `M74.891 37.232...` is mapped to `m 37.232,74.891...` instead of `m 74.891,37.232...`

Comment: You were right, thank you very much. I do have a another question, what determines the positioning of the drawing in the SVG? Because now it does render afghanistan, but when you try to view it, it's hidden for the most part. (I'll add my new code to my question)